# Cloud Run gRPC via Rust Tonic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rust, google-cloud-run, rust-tonic

I'm trying to build 2 Google Cloud Run containers that will communicate via gRPC using [Tonic](https://docs.rs/tonic/latest/tonic/index.html). The problem I'm running into is the "error trying to connect: invalid peer certificate: UnknownIssuer" issue.

I found [this exact issue](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/discussions/1285#discussioncomment-6874898) and it says all I need to do is add the `tls-roots` (and `tls`) feature flag to tonic and it will all magically work... however, that doesn't seem to be the case for me. I have tried just calling connect with my endpoint defined as the HTTPS URI of the listening container, but that does not work:

```
let dac = DataAccessClient::connect(BACKEND_URI.as_str()).await?;
```

I have also tried following the example in the [Tonic GitHub for GCP](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/blob/master/examples/src/gcp/client.rs), and that does not work either (using the same [`roots.pem`](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/blob/master/examples/data/gcp/roots.pem) file):

```
    let certs = std::fs::read_to_string("/roots.pem")
        .context("Reading certificate")?;

    let tls_config = ClientTlsConfig::new()
        .ca_certificate(Certificate::from_pem(certs));

    let channel = Channel::from_static(BACKEND_URI.as_str())
        .tls_config(tls_config)?
        .connect()
        .await?;

    let dac = DataAccessClient::new(channel);
```

The result is always the same error message: "error trying to connect: invalid peer certificate: UnknownIssuer"

Does anyone have a working example of 2 Cloud Run containers communicating via gRPC using Tonic? Or know where I might be going wrong with what I have?

Comment: Please delete or self-answer your question with its [resoution](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/discussions/1285#discussioncomment-7002679)